# Book featuring quantum mechanics used almost like magic?

Tags: story-identification

Can anyone help identify a sci-fi book where the main character uses quantum mechanics to an effect like magic?

At one point he bends probability so that he becomes "invisible" as he is sneaking around and keeps forcing dice to roll the number he wants to make sure the device is still working.

Comment: Not really a book, but the web serial "Fine Structure" (http://qntm.org/structure) has lots of elements similar to this idea.

Comment: @vsz - thank you for posting that  :)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27811/identify-a-story-on-quantum-indeterminacy-where-protagonist-has-to-quantum-se (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 14):

This happens in [*Quarantine*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarantine_%28Greg_Egan_novel%29) by [Greg Egan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greg_Egan). One of the plot threads is that researchers find a way to influence quantum-mechanical effects through human observation; this allows them to build a device that can influence probability and effectively allow someone to go undetected. The main character uses this device to sneak into a building, and checks that it is still working with an electronic dice generator.

Another important plot thread — which gave rise to the title — is that the solar system has been surrounded by an impenetrable shield that keeps humans from going out and keeps starlight from going in.