# Story on quantum indeterminacy: protagonist has to “quantum select” a portable computer’s state

Tags: story-identification, computers

Story: protagonist receives a device, which looks like a portable computer, and has to use his “quantum reality version selection” abilities to pick the one reality’s version where the computer has finished calculations.

After that is done, it is revealed that the object of calculations was some bio/nano-technological weapon that is released to the world shortly after, but is stopped without any harmful consequences.

2000–2008, full-length color movie, happy end included.

Comment: Was this an English language movie?

Comment: Was "quantum reality version-selection" actually used as a descriptor in the movie, or just your interpretation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds almost like [Greg Egan's *Quarantine*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarantine_(Greg_Egan_novel)) but as far as I know that's only a novel.

Comment: Once I had an accident of occasionally "dreaming" a book while reading to the grade that it was recalled as a movie later. (that episode is a clear antagonist of 'bad trip'..). But for this story, I would've remembered reading that in foreign language -- did a quick check on e-book sites and found no G. Egan's translated works. That means we still look for B movie.

Comment: No hard feelings, didn't think it was the correct answer... but I answer anyway hoping it will kick someone else's memory so they find the correct one.

Comment: so I finally found the time to read it. Well.. that is. That wasn't the movie.. now going to try to remember the measures I've been taking to damage my memory so much (hope they don't have a stackexchange site on some activities here)..

Comment: @kagali-san If the book described doesn't answer your question correctly you should not feel obligated to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds vaguely like [Paycheck](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0338337/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't by any chance The Ultimate Question to Life, the Universe and Everything? Because it reminds me of **The Hitchhiker's Guide To The Galaxy**, which is of course too benign, dull and British to be the thriller you're looking for.

Comment: No way, it had no starships, robots or towels involved.

Comment: @kagali-san: Well then what's the point?

Comment: @Beta, it still has(d) nanobacteria and ton of quantum physics for dummies.