# 90s (or earlier) book, stars blocked out from Earth by a veil set by aliens who may have feared humans

Tags: story-identification, books

I've been desperately searching for a book I loved on every level that I read when I was at school (20 odd years ago).

I've asked the local librarians, Google, you name it I've looked (even thought of calling my old schools to see if they would have my library record).

The few bits of memory I have of this book are that it was set on an Earth where the stars were blocked out by some other interstellar race with a veil or bubble of some kind.

The main character feels that this veil/bubble may have been put in place due to their fear of what the human race was capable of and often makes references to personal nano-tech upgrades and quotes the dollar price. I think it was about a detective or a guy who was trying to look for someone/something and used these devices on a nano scale to find them.

Comment: I can vaguely remember at least 3 different examples of this trope.  Even the 90a video game Star Control 2 used this trope.

Comment: even earlier duplicate at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27811/identify-a-story-on-quantum-indeterminacy-where-protagonist-has-to-quantum-se

Answer (score 29):

"Quarantine" by Greg Egan, published in 1992

[WIkipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarantine_%28Greg_Egan_novel%29) says:

> The novel is set in the near future (2034–2080), after the solar system has been surrounded by an impenetrable shield (constructed by either aliens or extra-solar humans) known as the Bubble. The Bubble permits no light to enter the solar system, and as a consequence the stars can no longer be seen. This seems to be mere background at first, but in fact it is central to the plot.

[image: Quarantine novel cover, Earth circled by the tagline "a novel of quantum catastrophe"]

Comment: Oh goodness, you kind soul I adore you. That is the book, I can't tell you how much I appreciate this.

Comment: @Krisnkaz you should mark this answer as accepted (the tick below the voting buttons)